# issue with Hibernate allocationSize for SequenceGenerator

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have read a lot using `@SequenceGenerator` - it increases real database sequence by one, multiple this value by 50 (default allocationSize value) - and then uses this value as entity ID. But found an issue where its not doing sequence.nextVal and not updating the sequence.

**Using Hibernate - 5.0.12**

**Sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_ENTITY_ID_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 CACHE 20;
```

**Here is my entity** -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_ENTITY")
public class TestEntity  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TEST_ENTITY_ID_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 2, sequenceName = "TEST_ENTITY_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TEST_ENTITY_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "COMNT_ID")
    private Long comntId;
    @Column(name = "VIEW_ID")
    private Long viewId;
```

**My Service code -**

```
TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
testEntity.setViewId(11l);
TestEntity testEntity1 = testEntityRepo.save(testEntity);
return testEntity1.toString();
```

First restart of my application my sequence current val as - `7`

**Attempt1:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=16, viewId=11}`
**Attempt2:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=17, viewId=11}`
**Attempt3:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=18, viewId=11}`
**Attempt4:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=19, viewId=11}`
**sequence currval** still same as -`7`
 After i restart the application
**Attempt5:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=20, viewId=11}`
**Attempt6:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=21, viewId=11}`
**sequence currval** still same as -`7`
 After i restart the application
**Attempt7:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=22, viewId=11}`
**Attempt8:** When i save `TestEntity` it generates Id as - `TestEntity{comntId=23, viewId=11}`
**sequence currval** still same as -`7`

**Just to note there is no difference even if i change it to `allocationSize = 1`**

> Is this expected behavior? Or am i missing anything here?

Comment: how is TEST_ENTITY_ID_SEQ defined?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli added the definition of the sequence

Comment: Why do you have allocation size 2 when you increment by 1?

Comment: i tried changing the size to 1 but it still does not bother my sequence value.

Comment: Have you checked the generated sql statements?

Comment: thanks @SimonMartinelli, after checking the sql i realized hibernate was actually doing `seq.nextVal`  and it was not reflecting in my other session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is i was using `select TEST_ENTITY_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual` to get the current values of the sequence from another session.

> The CURRVAL is SESSION specific; that is, each session might have a
>   DIFFERENT value than other sessions.

So when i queried from my application it started to give me correct values.